# Use Segmented Control Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, button, controls, uisegmentedcontrol

I have searched the web and youtube about segmented control, but I only find examples of how to change to a different view.

My goal is to take the selected value from the segmented control and use it in the action on another button.

I will try to explain what I mean :

```
@IBAction func segmentetControll(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
     value 1
     value 2
     value 3
}

@IBAction func calculateButton(_ sender: Any) {
    if value 1 {
        do this
    }
    else if value 2 {
        Do that
    }
    else if value 3 {
        Do thids
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to connect it via `@IBOutlet` to file.
Then you can use its index to do whatever you want.

```
@IBOutlet var segmentedControl: UISegmentedControl!

@IBAction func calculateButton(_ sender: Any) {
    let index = segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex
    //...
}
```

Comment: Thank all of you for quick response! Used the solution from Orkhan Alikhanov, and now it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

Putting the code in the IBAction method connected via the storyboard or Xib file is the correct approach. You can use strong types when hooking up the action to the control and write code such as:

```
@IBAction func calculateButton(_ sender: UISegmentedControl) {
    switch(sender.selectedSegmentIndex){
    case 1:
        // Do something
    case 2:
        // Do something
    case 3:
        // Do something
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need to create an `@IBOutlet var segmentedControl: UISegmentedControl?` property that connects to the segmented control in the Interface Builder, and then in the `calculateButton` method you can switch over `segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex`. Let me know if you need further explanation.